# How to show that $($grad $F)(a,b,c)$ is normal to $r^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$ at $(a,b,c)$?

Tags: vector-analysis

I need help with this problem:

> Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3$\
>   $\{\mathbf0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$F(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{r}, \quad \mathbf{r}\neq\mathbf0$$ where $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)$ and $r=\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+x^2)}$. Prove that $$(grad\ F)(\mathbf{r})=-\frac{1}{r^3}\mathbf{r}$$ Show that $($grad $F)(a,b,c)$ is normal to the sphere $r^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$ at the point $(a,b,c)$ and pints in the direction of increasing values of F. Find the equation of the tangent plane to the sphere $(a,b,c)$.

I've already proved that $(grad\ F)(\mathbf{r})=-\frac{1}{r^3}\mathbf{r}$, but I don't know hot to show that the $(grad\ F)(a,b,c)$ is normal to the sphere. Should I use dot product? Also how do I find the equation of the tangent plane? Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two facts about the gradient in this problem that you have to use. The first one, is that the gradient vector $\nabla F$ always points in the direction of maximum increase of $F$. The second one, is that the gradient vector is normal to the level surface of $F(x,y,z)$ at a point $(x,y,z)$. There are really good proofs [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DirectionalDeriv.aspx#Gradient_Defn) to the bottom of the page, under each blue note.

So, we have already solved half of the problem. Now to show that $\nabla F$ is perpendicular to the sphere $r^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ at a point $(a,b,c)$, we have to show that the sphere is the level surface of $F$ at the point $(a,b,c)$. The level surface of $F$ at a point $(a,b,c)$ is the surface given by the equation $F(x,y,z) = k$ where $k = F(a,b,c)$.
So we have

$$ F(x,y,z) = F(a,b,c) \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}  \\ \sqrt{r^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} \\ r^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$

So the sphere $r^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ (which is a sphere centered at the origin that has the point $(a,b,c)$ on it's surface) is indeed the level surface of $F$ at the point $(a,b,c)$ and so $\nabla F(a,b,c)$ is perpendicular to it.

To find the equation of the tangent plane to the sphere at the point $(a,b,c)$, you need a normal vector to the sphere in that point. We already have it: it's the gradient. The equation of a tangent plane to a surface at a point $P$ is given by:

$$ \vec n \cdot \left(\vec r - \vec P\right) = 0 $$
where $\vec P$ is the position vector of the point $P$ and $\vec n$ is the normal vector. So in our case, the equation for the plane is:

$$ \nabla F \cdot \left(\left\langle x, y, z \right\rangle - \left\langle a, b, c \right\rangle\right) = 0 $$ and then just carry the calculations on.

Comment: The level set is always $F(x,y,z)=F(a,b,c)$ where $(a,b,c)$ is a point? For example, in the level set of $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ is $f(x,y)=k$ where $k=f(a,b)$?

Comment: The level curves/surfaces/higher-dimension-equivalent of a function f of multiple variables is where $f(\vec P) = k$ and $\vec P$ is in a sense a notation for describing $f(x,y,...)$. Now, if we have a point $(a,b)$, we know that it might be on a level curve of the function $f(x,y)$. But, if $(a,b)$ is on a level curve, $f(x,y) = k$, it must be that $f(a,b) = k$.

Comment: You can read more about level curves to the bottom of [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/MultiVrbleFcns.aspx) page.

Comment: Ok, I'll definitely read more about them. So, if I have $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, then the level set $x^2-y^2=c$ at point $(a,b)$ means that $f(a,b)=c$, thus the level set is $f(x,y)=f(a,b)\Rightarrow x^2-y^2=a^2-b^2$?

Comment: Yes, briefly said. It's because $(a,b)$ has to be on that level set and so $f(a,b) = c$